# Creating new SparkContext for each SparkStep in MRJob/ pySpark

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, mrjob

I am new to pySpark and I'm trying to implement a multi-step EMR/Spark job using MRJob, do I need to create a new SparkContext for each SparkStep, or can I share the same SparkContext for all SparkSteps?

I tried to look up the [MRJob manual](http://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/spark.html) but unfortunately it was not clear on this.

Can someone please advise what's the correct approach?

1. Creating a separate SparkContext:

   ```
   class MRSparkJob(MRJob):
       def spark_step1(self, input_path, output_path):
           from pyspark import SparkContext
           sc = SparkContext(appName='appname')
           ...
           sc.stop()

       def spark_step2(self, input_path, output_path):
           from pyspark import SparkContext
           sc = SparkContext(appName='appname')
           ...
           sc.stop()

       def steps(self):
           return [SparkStep(spark=self.spark_step1),
                   SparkStep(spark=self.spark_step2)]

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       MRSparkJob.run()
   ```
2. Create a single SparkContext and share it among differnt SparkSteps

   ```
   class MRSparkJob(MRJob):

       sc = None

       def spark_step1(self, input_path, output_path):
           from pyspark import SparkContext
           self.sc = SparkContext(appName='appname')
           ...


       def spark_step2(self, input_path, output_path):
           from pyspark import SparkContext

           ... (reuse the same self.sc)
           self.sc.stop()

       def steps(self):
           return [SparkStep(spark=self.spark_step1),
                   SparkStep(spark=self.spark_step2)]

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       MRSparkJob.run()
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Dave at [MRJob discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mrjob/iU40G7e9khk), we should create a new SparkContext for each step, as each step is a completely new invocation of Hadoop and Spark (ie. #1 above is the correct approach).